# Extract RGB using simpleCV

Tags: python, simplecv

I'll use this picture as an example[image]

I need to extract the RGB values and compare them with all of the color values to see if I can figure out which color is in it without hard coding it.

For example I get (4,5,0) and I determined this color = red. I don't know if those are the real values of red, but it's an example.

How can I extract the RGB values from the inside of the red box and how can I search for the color that corresponds to those values.

this is what I tried:

```
img = Image('car.png')

pixel = img.getPixel(120, 150)

print(pixel)
```

This retrieves the rgb on those dimensions, but I need an average around that whole box.

Please explain solution, thanks

Comment: All values? Average value? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @jonrsharpe posted what I tried

Comment: Still not enough information: how are you determining the position of the box? At the simplest, why not iterate over each pixel?

Comment: If that's all you've tried, it's pretty pathetic. I'd argue that you're beyond help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well `.getPixel(120, 150)` x = 120 and y = 150, But I don't really know how to get an average of a set amount of pixels

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the compliment. I thought I was suppose to get help on this site not get insulted. I never said I was a SUPER programmer. Have you noticed my rating?

Comment: @chelo666 Don't take these comments too personally: [unpleasant comments are much too common on this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191089/why-do-we-let-hostile-users-dictate-the-perception-of-stack-overflow), unfortunately.

Comment: @AndersonGreen, I admit my comment was harsh, perhaps more than any other I've made on SO in 5+ years. But I still stand by it. Trying to calculate an average without any kind of a looping construct just seems hopelessly naive - it's like they didn't even try. You can't blame that on not being "a SUPER programmer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea of what you should do:

```
    width = XX
    height = YY

    #crops to (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) when x2>x1 and y2>y1
    frame = img[width/4:(width/4+width/2), height/4:(height/4+height/2)]
```

And then,

```
    r = np.array(frame[:,:,0])
    avg_r = np.average(r)
```

Repeat for G and B.